# WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!

Tags: dkms

Why and how to correct dkms status output

```
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.4.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: It means that there are two wireguard modules on your system. I don't know what wireguard is, but it's possible that it's included in 20.04. Do `modinfo wireguard` and see where it finds it.

Comment: the conflict was due to wireguard-dkms, which I removed and now is OK